# Setup Amazon CloudFront for EC2 instance as front just like a CloudFlare setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I have a website installed and working correctly on my EC2 instance. I want to setup CloudFront and use it as a front CDN service just like CloudFlare. (My old stack was like that; I was able to serve the whole website through CloudFlare just by adding proper DNS records)

Here is what I did:

1. I created a CloudFront web distribution.
2. I've setup an origin as secret.example.com (secret.example.com works normally on browser)
3. I've added [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) as CNAME to my CloudFront distribution.
4. I've set a CNAME record to point www subdomin to my CloudFront's distribution domain.

Here is what happens:
I can't connect to my website through CloudFront distribution's domain. Thus, [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) doesn't work.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

My apologies if you've already taken a look at the Amazon documentation regarding the subject, but I've once tested this solution and it worked fine for me:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DownloadDistS3AndCustomOrigins.html#concept_CustomOrigin

Take a look and see if you have missed a step (for example with the headers)

Comment: The thing is... These docs are saying that I should use my-ec2.compute.amazonaws.com (my ec2's public domain) as origin. However when I use this; browser just redirects me to my public ip address.

Comment: any updates on this? Running into the same issue. Using an Alias is often recommended, Not sure why, instead of CNAME.